# SQL Server : the last statement included within a function must be a return statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm writing the following function to check the row in a table based on the parameter that I pass to function and return a data-type bit result.

Here is the function:

```
create function dbo.udf_my_func(@var1 varchar(15), @var2 varchar(30))
returns bit as  
begin 
    if not exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 = 1)
    begin
        return 0
    end

    if exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 = @var2)
    begin
        return 1
    end

    if exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 <> @var2)
    begin
        return 0
    end

end
go
```

But I'm getting this error:

> The last statement included within a function must be a return statement

Please let me know how to fix this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should it return if all if's fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the standard type of writing a function that is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION <Scalar_Function_Name, sysname, FunctionName> 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>
)
RETURNS <Function_Data_Type, ,int>
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> <Function_Data_Type, ,int>

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> = <@Param1, sysname, @p1>

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result>

END
GO
```

So Your function should be like this:
(Note that I reverse the order of your checkings)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_my_func(@var1 varchar(15), @var2 varchar(30))
RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ResultVar bit = 0
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Sample_table(nolock) WHERE var1 = @var1 AND var2 <> @var2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ResultVar = 0
    END
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Sample_table(nolock) WHERE var1 = @var1 AND var2 = @var2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ResultVar = 1
    END
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Sample_table(nolock) WHERE var1 = @var1 AND var2 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ResultVar = 0
    END
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
GO
```

---

But You can use many better ways like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_my_func(@var1 varchar(15), @var2 varchar(30))
RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ResultVar bit = 0
    SELECT @ResultVar = CASE 
                            WHEN var1 = @var1 AND var2 <> @var2 THEN 0
                            WHEN var1 = @var1 AND var2 = @var2 THEN 1
                            WHEN var1 = @var1 AND var2 = 1 THEN 0
                            ELSE @ResultVar
                        END
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not define the return value for this case: var1 <> @var 1

```
create function dbo.udf_my_func(@var1 varchar(15), @var2 varchar(30))
returns bit as  
begin 


    if not exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 = 1)
    begin
        return 0
    end


        if exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 = @var2)
    begin
        return 1
    end

        if exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 <> @var2)
    begin
        return 0
    end

    -- else
    return 0 
end
go
```

You could optimize you code:

```
create function dbo.udf_my_func(@var1 varchar(15), @var2 varchar(30))
    returns bit as  
    begin 


        if exists (select 1 from Sample_table(nolock) where var1 = @var1 and var2 = @var2)
        begin
            return 1
        end
        -- place other conditions that return 1 here

        -- else
        return 0 
    end
    go
```